# Why it appears the error "General error: 1005 Can't create table"?

Tags: laravel

I have these two migration files one to create a faq_channels table and another to create a faq_questions table. However, I'm not understanding why it is showing an error:

```
    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `test`.`faq_questions` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `faq_questions` add const
raint `faq_questions_channel_id_foreign` foreign key (`channel_id`) references `faq_channels` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Do you know why?

```
// create_faq_channels_table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('faq_channels', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('channel');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

// create_faq_questions_table
Schema::create('faq_questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('channel_id');
    $table->string('question');
    $table->text('response');

    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('channel_id')->references('id')->on('faq_channels')->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have these **two** migration files one to create a faq_channels table
>   and another to create a faq_questions table.

Make sure that migration file for 'faq_channels' table runs before the migration file for 'faq_questions' table. Generally this type of error rises when the parent table is not created before declaring foreign key constraint.

Also edit your migration files according to Talha F.'s answer.